# Python For Loop in List with fuction

Tags: python, for-loop

I got an issue to solve a problem.

When I run the code:

```
def get_state_name(list):
    for lists in list:
        print(lists)

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

get_state_name(list)
```

It returns only `'a'`

But without defining fuction, for example:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for lists in mylist:
    print(lists)
```

it returns entire list:

```
a
b
c
d
```

why is it happening?

Comment: Your first example doesn't run, it gives a type error because you pass `list` into your function. If you change `list` to `mylist` it runs fine.

Comment: get_state_name(mylist)

Comment: Do not name your variable as `list` because `list` is a built-in data type.

Comment: Your function __returns__ nothing, it just prints.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the keyword "list"! It is default keyword and you should not use it for any other use (for ex variable name)

Also you are passing "list" as an argument in the last line, that variable is not defined outside of the function. You should pass "mylist" as your argument there.

Saying that, this is the code which will do the work. Compare it with yours.

Hope it will help:)

```
def get_state_name(my_list):
    for lists in my_list:
        print(lists)

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

get_state_name(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've Created mylist and passing wrong argument "list" .Just Because of this mistake [image]

**Correct Your Code :**

```
def get_state_name(list):
    for lists in list:
        print(lists)

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

get_state_name(mylist)
```

**Now It Returns Correct Output**

> a
>   b
>   c
>   d